# Post Updated readonly values to Action in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, nouislider

I have below `form` which is of `method=get`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main-search", id = "frmsearch", role = "form" })) {
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="type">Property Type</label>
      @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.searchModel.CategoriesId, Model.searchModel.Categories, htmlAttributes: new { id = "type", multiple = "multiple", @class = "animate", data_transition_parent = ".dropdown-menu", title = "All" })
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="location">Location</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.searchModel.LocationID, Model.searchModel.Locations, htmlAttributes: new { id = "location", multiple = "multiple", @class = "animate", data_transition_parent = ".dropdown-menu", title = "All" })
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Status</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.searchModel.StatusID, Model.searchModel.Status, htmlAttributes: new { id = "status", multiple = "multiple", @class = "animate", data_transition_parent = ".dropdown-menu", title = "All" })
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Price</label>
      <div class="ui-slider" id="price-slider-category" data-value-min="@Model.searchModel.MinPrice" data-value-max="@Model.searchModel.MaxPrice" data-value-type="price" data-currency="&#8377;" data-currency-placement="before">
        <div class="values clearfix">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchModel.MinPrice, htmlAttributes: new { id = "value-min", @class = "value-min", name = "value-min[]", @readonly = "readonly", style = "padding:0px" }) 
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchModel.MaxPrice, htmlAttributes: new { id = "value-max", @class = "value-max", name = "value-max[]", @readonly = "readonly", style = "padding:0px" })
        </div>
        <div class="element"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <button type="submit" style="color:white" id="searchSubmit" class="btn btn-block blue waves-effect">
        <i class="fa fa-search"> </i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
  </div>
  <!--/.col-md-6-->
</div>
<!--/.row-->
}
```

and I have this `JS` to post `form` values through `AJAX`

```
$(document).on('click', '#searchSubmit', function (e) {
        var _form = $(this).closest('form');
        var _url = _form.attr('action');
        var formData = _form.serialize();
        var request = $.get(_url, formData);
        request.complete(function (response) {

        })
})
```

Here is my `model`

```
public class SearchFilters
{
    public SearchFilters()
    {
         MinPrice = 10000;
         MaxPrice=8000000;
    }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public int[] CategoriesId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Locations { get; set; }
    public int[] LocationID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
    public int[] StatusID { get; set; }

    public int MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int MaxPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my `controller` method to process the search request.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search([Bind(Prefix = "searchModel")]SearchFilters smodel)
{
     ProjectsViewModel model = new ProjectsViewModel();
     //search db and fill model
     return PartialView("_PropertyDetails", model);
}
```

The UI rendering happens for min and max value using `noUiSlider` plugin and thus inputs are `readonly` but gets updated through `update` option of `noUiSlider`. But whenever model is received in Server it comes as default value assigned to model variables even after update. The values doesn't get updated when inspected in `DOM` but its reflected in `UI`. Yes it is because of `readonly` property of `textbox` but **Is there any other way to post the readonly property values in these type of situations?** Below are few screenshots of how `UI` looks and `DOM` and `model` values when it is received.

**UI**

[image]

**DOM**

[image]

**Model**

[image]

**UPDATE**

I can see the posted values in `URL` as `...searchModel.MinPrice=₹2%2C189%2C090.00&searchModel.MaxPrice=₹5%2C772%2C480.00` But not in model. Not sure how to get on this..

Comment: Are you formatting `min` and `max` anywhere on UI with `,` delimiters? And also with `₹` currency.

Comment: can you remove the formatting and give it a try? also do remove `₹`.

Comment: @ramiramilu sure.. will see that option too once..

Comment: post the url as well once you give it a try, in fact post the entire url.

Comment: Just a hunch, but your `noUiSlider` is updating those inputs to the string value which includes the currency symbol and commas. Your model is expecting an `int`. It doesn't find `MinPrice` and `MaxPrice` as ints in the values that you `POST`, so it populates the model with the defaults from the constructor.

Comment: @ethorn10.. true that.. Hadn't though on that.. Well I converted it to string now and will manipulate the same on serverside to get an `integer`.. Working awesome now.. Can you or ramiramilu post this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ramiramilu Can anyone of you, either you or ethorn post this as an answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`₹` and `,` formatting makes the `MinPrice` and `MaxPrice` as strings. And as a result those are not getting bind to `int` properties. Just remove the formatting and send them in `GET`, then they will be getting bind to int properties.

Comment: Cool.. Thanks much for the help buddy.. :)